# retrieve twilio transcription text in php without knowing sid

Tags: php, twilio

I am working on an twilio app which voice is transcribed and then converted to text. Everything is functional until it comes to retrieving the transcription text.  I am aware I can retrieve transcription code if I know the "sid"  but what if I want the transcription code on the fly and do not know the "sid". In other words I would like the newest transcription from phone number "555-555-1212"  all I can find is the code below.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC1240edf87a1d3b6717472af6deda4ce7";
$token = "{{ auth_token }}";
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$client->account->transcriptions->delete("TR8c61027b709ffb038236612dc5af8723");
?>
```

Thanks in advance!
Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for my original question =)

```
<?php
//RETRIEVE NUMBERS LAST TRANSCRIPTION
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$i=0;
foreach($client->account->transcriptions->getIterator(0, 50, array('Status' =>  'completed', 'To' => ''.$_GET['number'].'')) as $call)  {  
//now use the sid to get the transcription text using a seperate rest call.
if($i==1) break;
$transcription = $client->account->transcriptions->get($call->sid);
$sms_text = $transcription->transcription_text;
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to get the SID for the call, but that is easy enough to do if you know the phone number, and optionally a date range to look for (my PHP is rusty so you may need to touch this up):

```
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "{{ sid }}"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Get calls to a number on or after a certain date.
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array("Status" => "completed", "To" => "555-555-1212","StartTime" => "2013-10-26")) as $call)  {
    echo $call->sid
    //now use the sid to get the transcription text using a seperate rest call.
    $transcription = $client->account->transcriptions->get($call->sid);
    echo $transcription->transcription_text;    
}
```

Comment: echo $transcription->transcription_text; throws the following error --> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The requested resource was not found'

It seems call sid and transcrption sid are totally different...

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Another option is if you are using the `<Record>` verb is to you can set the transcribeCallback parameter:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-transcribe-callback

This lets you give Twilio a URL that we will request when a transcription is completed.

Hope that helps.